# CardLayout using JMenu sending error messages

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, cardlayout

Hi guys I wanted to create a simple program where I can control each JPanel by using menuItems. For example if I select File->New where New is JmenuItem it will show a JPanel named newPanel. Also if I select Edit->Edit it will show JPanel named editPanel along with the objects added to it. So far this is what I have constructed:

```
public class CardLayoutwithMenuBar extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuBar menu;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenu editMenu;
    private JMenu exitMenu;

    private JMenuItem openItem;
    private JMenuItem newItem;
    private JMenuItem editItem;
    private JMenuItem exitItem;

    private JPanel newPanel;
    private JPanel openPanel;
    private JPanel editPanel;
    private JPanel exitPanel;

    static private CardLayout cardView;
    static private JPanel cardPanel;


    public CardLayoutwithMenuBar(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("Controlling Different Panel Using CardLayout");
        this.setSize(400, 150);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create Menu bar and add to Frame
        menu = new JMenuBar();
        this.setJMenuBar(menu);

        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        exitMenu = new JMenu("Exit");

        menu.add(fileMenu);
        menu.add(editMenu);
        menu.add(exitMenu);

        newItem = new JMenuItem("New File");
        openItem = new JMenuItem("File Open");
        editItem = new JMenuItem("Edit Entry");
        exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        fileMenu.add(openItem);
        editMenu.add(editItem);
        exitMenu.add(exitItem);

        //Declare object cardView and cardPanel and set layout of cardPanel to CardLayout
        cardView = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel = new JPanel();
        cardPanel.setLayout(cardView);


        //Create sub-panels that would correspond to each function in the menu item ex. newItem, openItem etc...
        newPanel = new JPanel();
        openPanel = new JPanel();
        editPanel = new JPanel();
        exitPanel = new JPanel();


        //add the sub-panels to the main cardpanel 
        cardPanel.add("New", newPanel);
        cardPanel.add("Open", openPanel);
        cardPanel.add("Edit",editPanel);
        cardPanel.add("Exit",exitPanel);

        newItem.addActionListener(this);
        openItem.addActionListener(this);
        editItem.addActionListener(this);
        exitItem.addActionListener(this);

        this.getContentPane().add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String menuItemAction = evt.getActionCommand();

            if (menuItemAction.equals("New File")){
                cardView.show(newPanel, "New");
            }
            else if (menuItemAction.equals("File Open")){
                cardView.show(openPanel, "Open");
            }
            else if (menuItemAction.equals("Edit Entry")){
                cardView.show(editPanel, "Edit");
            }
            else if (menuItemAction.equals("Exit")){
                cardView.show(exitPanel, "Exit");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Opppsss you pressed something else");
        }
    }   
}
```

When I try to run this program I always get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
    at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(CardLayout.java:404)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(CardLayout.java:526)
    at com.JMenuSample.CardLayoutwithMenuBar.actionPerformed(CardLayoutwithMenuBar.java:132)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
.... and the list goes on
```

Can anyone help me out to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- have to use proper method for `CardLayout` - [`public void show(Container parent,       String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29)
- then to use `cardView.show(cardPanel, "New");` `(insted of cardView.show(newPanel, "New");)`
- for rest of `newPanel as Container` to stays and to change only 2nd. parameter in `String` form

Comment: hi thanks a lot mKorbel that worked! I am fairly new to GUI/Swing I guess I have lot of things to learn.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to mKorbel (beat me to it)

however here it is:

- dont call `setVisible` before the `JFrame` has been created.
- dont use setSize rather find an appropriate `LayoutManager` or override `getPreferredSize` of `JComponent`
- call `pack()` on `JFrame` instance
- use `switch` block on `String`s (from java 7) rather than `if` statement as it is more efficient
- Dont `extend` the `JFrame` class unnecessarily

The reason for the error is here:

```
  if (menuItemAction.equals("New File")){
                cardView.show(newPanel, "New");
            }
            else if (menuItemAction.equals("File Open")){
                cardView.show(openPanel, "Open");
            }
            else if (menuItemAction.equals("Edit Entry")){
                cardView.show(editPanel, "Edit");
            }
            else if (menuItemAction.equals("Exit")){
                cardView.show(exitPanel, "Exit");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Opppsss you pressed something else");
        }
```

your parent is your `cardPanel` and not the panel you want to show, that is given by the string argument:

```
cardView.show(cardPanel, "New");
```

see changed code below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CardLayoutWithMenuBar implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuBar menu;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenu editMenu;
    private JMenu exitMenu;
    private JMenuItem openItem;
    private JMenuItem newItem;
    private JMenuItem editItem;
    private JMenuItem exitItem;
    private JPanel newPanel;
    private JPanel openPanel;
    private JPanel editPanel;
    private JPanel exitPanel;
    private CardLayout cardView;
    private JPanel cardPanel;

    public CardLayoutWithMenuBar() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Controlling Different Panel Using CardLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents(frame);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        String menuItemAction = evt.getActionCommand();

        switch (menuItemAction) {
            case "New File":
                cardView.show(cardPanel, "New");
                break;
            case "File Open":
                cardView.show(cardPanel, "Open");
                break;
            case "Edit Entry":
                cardView.show(cardPanel, "Edit");
                break;
            case "Exit":
                cardView.show(cardPanel, "Exit");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opppsss you pressed something else");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        //Create Menu bar and add to Frame
        menu = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menu);

        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        exitMenu = new JMenu("Exit");

        menu.add(fileMenu);
        menu.add(editMenu);
        menu.add(exitMenu);

        newItem = new JMenuItem("New File");
        openItem = new JMenuItem("File Open");
        editItem = new JMenuItem("Edit Entry");
        exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        fileMenu.add(openItem);
        editMenu.add(editItem);
        exitMenu.add(exitItem);

        //Declare object cardView and cardPanel and set layout of cardPanel to CardLayout
        cardView = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel = new JPanel(cardView);


        //Create sub-panels that would correspond to each function in the menu item ex. newItem, openItem etc...
        newPanel = new JPanel();
        openPanel = new JPanel();
        editPanel = new JPanel();
        exitPanel = new JPanel();


        //add the sub-panels to the main cardpanel 
        cardPanel.add("New", newPanel);
        cardPanel.add("Open", openPanel);
        cardPanel.add("Edit", editPanel);
        cardPanel.add("Exit", exitPanel);

        newItem.addActionListener(this);
        openItem.addActionListener(this);
        editItem.addActionListener(this);
        exitItem.addActionListener(this);

       frame.getContentPane().add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        //create frame and components on EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CardLayoutWithMenuBar cardLayoutWithMenuBar = new CardLayoutWithMenuBar();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice David I'll keep this in my mind. Also I didn't separate the initialize components like you did because this is part of bigger program. But I am not sure how to implement so I just tried it on simple ones. Anyway can you tell me why I need to write the line SwingUtilities.invokeLater... at main? Is it common practice or to make the program safer to execute?

Comment: @dimas Yes sorry did it for readability :). have a look at these links to further explain it for you: [Initial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [EDT (Event-Dispatch-Thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Comment: No worries David, am just asking because am self-studying java and I have no one to ask except in forums so all of my coding style are to the best of my understanding on how it works or the logic flow. I don't know any industry kind of styles, so again I would like to thank you for the tips and links you gave me.

Comment: @dimas +1 we all have to learn from somewhere glad to be of help :)